# Explanation on while loop condition

Tags: java

I have the following code with a while loop in it, However, I am not sure what one part of the while loops does.

```
    int a=nums[i];
    while(i+1<nums.length&&(nums[i+1]-nums[i])==1)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

I have a nums array and need to create a summary range of it. Can you please explain what the parameters of the while loop mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one parameter or expression to a `while` loop: the condition that keeps the loop running if it evaluates to `true` or ends the loop if it evaluates to `false`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.

Given that in the body of the loop, `i` is being incremented, the code would be better served with a `for` loop. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

The code has a compound condition, both of which must be `true` for the body of the loop to be executed. Both must be true since the boolean AND operator `&&` is used.

The first condition checks that an OutOfBounds error does not occur by checking that `i+1` does not exceed the array `nums` length and in fact is at most one less the length. The second condition checks that the following element is exactly 1 greater than the current element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not convinced it would be clearer as a for loop: `for (; i+1<nums.length&&(nums[i+1]-nums[i])==1; i++) {}` is not obvious code.

Comment: @AndyTurner Could change up how `i` is used but still equivalent:

`for (i += 1; i < nums.length && nums[i]-nums[i-1] == 1; i++) {}`

But I see your point, it's a bit tricky out of context.

Comment: if both you guys, alan sereb and @iiKop47 answered my question, who do I mark correct answer? Thanks for your help

Comment: @JDog1999 doesn't matter. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

1) While index + 1 is less than the nums array length (to prevent OutOfBoundsException for next condition)

2) And next element of the array minus the current element of the array equal to one

Answer (score 0):

In this while loop there are two conditions connected with `&&` operator. so both condition s have to be fullfill. In first condition check weather index `i+1` is less then to your array size and second depends upon perticular value of index `i` and `i+1` .loop will be continue till both condition satisfied and index will be increase by 1. As soon as one of those condition will be false loop will be terminate.
.
You can also use for loop instead of while...it's quite easy to summerise arraylist . `for( int i=0;i<nums.lenght;i++){ nums[i];}`